# How to write this system in latex?

Tags: math-mode

[image]
How do you write this in latex?

Comment: `$\mathscr{E}(\Lambda)$`, if I remember well, because the image is not very clear.

Comment: @Sebastiano It requires the mathrsfs package I think

Comment: @EdoardoSerra I have upvoted your comment: see my answer :-).

Answer (score 1):

Here there is your image with `LaTeX` code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\[\mathscr{E}(\Lambda)\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I realized that, i forgot to use that package

Comment: @Benjamin I hope I've helped you, but I'm also inviting you to read a [guide](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) to your first steps in LaTeX. You'll find lots of them on the net. My best regards.